# Token to show only first term in Page Title module

Tags: tokens

I am using [Page Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_title) module and patterns to auto create them. One of the tokens for Page Title when creating content is taxonomy term.

Since users can add as many terms in content i would like to limit Page Title to only use first term added by the user.

Is there a way to do this with tokens ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delta values for field are available in token
[image]

As the description says delta start with 0 try using token as `[node:field-page-title:0]`, remember to replace your field machine name.